# -[CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization] or -[CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization] error

Tags: iphone, mapkit, ios8, core-location, xcode6

This is my code, showing both the alert and the blue dot for the current position on the map:

**MapName.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>


@interface MapName : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *MapName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

@end
```

**MapName.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
}
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

//Center the map
[self gotoLocation];

//Show current position
_MapName.showsUserLocation = YES;

}
```

I've added the key `NSLocationWhenIsUseUsageDescription` as a string to the Info.plist.
I'm still getting the same error on Xcode.

Comment: Please be more specific as to what you're seeing, and how it differs from what you'd expect to happen. What error are you encountering?

Comment: Everything's working fine on iPhone 5s: when I open the app I get the alert to allow access to my location and when I do grant access I get the actual position (blue dot). But as I press the allow button I get the message "Trying to start MapKit location updates without prompting for location authorization. Must call -[CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization] or -[CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization] first." on Xcode6. And if I use the Xcode simulator I don't get the blue dot, even if the simulated position is correctly selected.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is due to both:

```
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

and

```
_MapName.showsUserLocation = YES;
```

You need to check if the user has given permission before you call these. Also make sure you turn off User Location in the MKMapKit on the storyboard (this one took me days to track down).

Do something like:

```
CLAuthorizationStatus authorizationStatus= [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];

if (authorizationStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized ||
    authorizationStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways ||
    authorizationStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse) {

    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];       
    _MapName.showsUserLocation = YES;        

}
```

Depending on your app you may not want to ask for the user's permission on launch since that is not recommended.

Comment: Thanx Jerome!! I'll try it right away! I've seen that other apps are asking for permission right at lauch (eg. Skyscanner) so, since my app consists of 10 different maps, maybe it's better asking only once at the beginning. My iPad version has just been put up for distribution so I guess that's not a problem with Apple. I'm sorry it took you days to figure out the Storyboard user location option (I should have said I've used it). Therefore I really appreciate your effort!! Thanx a lot

Comment: @Max1980 Yeah of course you can ask permission right at launch and depending on your app you might want to. I know since my app, Pinpoint - Stay together, even when you're apart!, has a sign up process we noticed a large increase in the user conversion rate (via Flurry) when we moved permission access to the appropriate parts of the app. For instance, we ask for location permission when the user is on the map, address book permission when the user goes to add a friend, etc. Apple won't reject you one way or another.

Comment: For more detail on implementing this for less experienced iOS developers like myself, this article was extremely helpful. http://nevan.net/2014/09/core-location-manager-changes-in-ios-8/

Answer (score 4):

The error message is pretty literal. Don't call `[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation]` until you have authorization. Your `[self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization]`, per the docs, is asynchronous.

> When the current authorization status is `kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined`, this method runs asynchronously and prompts the user to grant permission to the app to use location services.

This means you are both prompting for access as well as starting your scan at the same time.

Instead, try implementing `-[CLLocationManagerDelegate locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:]` and starting your scan there after it's been determined that you have authorization.

Comment: Thanx for the answer @incanus. Where should implement the -[CLLocationManagerDelegate locationManager: didChangeAuthorizationStatus:] tho? I'm still doing it wrong I suppose

Comment: I've put everything in the Delegate files and it's now working without any error on Xcode6, as in the answer example. Can't get it working only when I open a random map in my app: the alert shows right when I open the app for the first time. Is that the only possible way?

Comment: I got this warning even though I *was* waiting until the user had granted permission in the Settings app alert; the key was as Jerome Miastkowski (above) states: in the storyboard/xib file you have to clear the "Shows [_] User Location" checkbox for the Map View in Xcode's Attributes Inspector (4th pane in Xcode's Utilities panel on the right). It's cleared by default, but I had checked it rather than have to set this flag in code (self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;). Wrong choice for iOS 8, it seems, needs to be clear *until* you're granted access.

Answer (score 3):

On swift :

```
  let locationManager: CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
  let authorizationStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()


  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if(authorizationStatus == .AuthorizedWhenInUse || authorizationStatus == .AuthorizedAlways) {
       locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    else
    {
      locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters

}
```

Don't forget to add into *Info.plist* file these keys:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The keyword in the info file is ("In" instead of "Is"):

```
NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
```

Comment: Sorry, typing mistake. It is actually in instead of is. Working fine on iPhone 5s but getting the error and not showing the current location on Xcode6

Comment: Debug and see whether you ever entered the if block. You are using ios 8 sdk?

Comment: I am using ios 8 sdk indeed @PeterPeiGuo

Comment: See this explanation: http://nevan.net/2014/09/core-location-manager-changes-in-ios-8/ (update to iOS 8 + Mapkit)

Answer (score 0):

This way is working without errors on Xcode6:

**AppDelegate.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize locationManager = _locationManager;


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary     *)launchOptions
 {
//Current position
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];

return YES;
}
@end
```

The alert message shows when you open the app for the first time

Answer (score 0):

Based off of Jerome's response, I translated the answer that worked for me to Swift.

```
    let authorizationStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()

    if(authorizationStatus == .AuthorizedWhenInUse || authorizationStatus == .AuthorizedAlways) {
           self.findMyLocation()
    }
```

Note: From what I read in the documents, there is no `kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized` equivalent in Swift.