# ios 8.0+: CLLocationManager does not ask for location permission properly

Tags: ios, mapkit, cllocationmanager

There is a question [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062509/location-services-not-working-in-ios-8) talking about this but I tried adding the string in Info.plist and asked for locManager.request..InUse.... When I launch the app, I can see the alert view poping up but before I do anything(allow or do not allow), it gets dismissed and there is a warning message printed out in debug console.

a basic code skeleton is like the following:
    let locManager = CLLocationManager()
    locManager.requestwheninuseauthorization()
    // code to ask the map to track user location

Comment: seems I need to implement this delegate... [Another stackoverflow question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25978774/2858599

Comment: See this answer, you'll get it

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25916841/cllocationmanager-startupdatinglocation-not-calling-locationmanagerdidupdateloc/26604933#26604933